# Does it take very long time to load CUDA program on Tesla C1060?

Tags: cuda

I had my CUDA code run on Linux server,RHEL5.3/Tesla C1060/CUDA 2.3  but it is much slower than I expect

However the data from cuda profiler is fast enough

So it seems that it spent very long time to load the program and the time isn't profiled

Am I right?

I use such code to test whether I'm right

```
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

#define B 1
#define T 1

__global__ void test()
{
}

int main()
{
    clock_t start=clock();
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    test<<<B,T>>>();
    clock_t end=clock();
    printf("time:%dms\n",end-start);
}
```

and use the command "time" as well as the clock() funtction used in the code to measure the 
time

```
nvcc -o test test.cu
time ./test
```

the result is

```
time:4s


real 0m3.311s
user 0m0.005s
sys  0m2.837s
```

on my own PC,which is Win 8/CUDA5.5/GT 720M/, the same code runs much faster.

Comment: Are you really running this using CUDA 2.3 (ie. from June 2009?)

Comment: Might be system load related or legacy functionality of CUDA.

Comment: It' our old linux server...and I stared using it several day ago...seems it has not been used for a very long time...

Comment: It is likely to be driver loading time. The driver from that era would unload after a period of inactivity. If you run your program twice in succession, I would expect that the second run to be faster.

Comment: @talonmies if you post your comment as an answer, I would upvote it.

Comment: get your server upgraded to a recent version of CUDA.  You are wasting your time struggling with a very old version of the CUDA tools that may have any number of defects that have been fixed by now.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux CUDA driver of that era (probably 185 series IIRC)  had a "feature" whereby the driver would unload several internal driver components whenever there was not a client connected to the driver. With display GPUs where X11 was active at all times, this was rarely a problem, but for compute GPUs it lead to large latency on first application runs while the driver reinitialised itself, and loss of device settings such as compute exclusive mode, fan speed, etc.

The normal solution was to run the `nvidia-smi` utility in daemon mode - it acts as a client and stops the the driver from deintialising. Something like this:

```
nvidia-smi --loop-continuously --interval=60 --filename=/var/log/nvidia-smi.log &
```

run as root should solve the problem

Comment: It seems the problem comes from cudaSetDevice; Sometimes if I choose cudaSetDevice(2), the code could run as fast as I expect, while sometimes, it is as slow as cudaSetDevice(0)...so may I ask what would happen if I don't call cudaSetDevice explicitly in my code? whichi card will the program choose?